# Office 365: Get a recurring report of all of the email addresses a company has been in contact with

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365

I've been scratching my head on this one... I can't seem to figure out a solution. The purpose for this is that every month the list of email addresses get uploaded into Mailchimp, and Mailchimp sends out an invite to the new contacts generated from that list asking them to join the mailchimp mailing list.

Anyone got any bright ideas on how to do this easily?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Its doable with powershell, but not easy.